# Representing 2 digits in 4 digits ArcMap attribute table?

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I would like to represent the 2 digits in the attribute table of the ArcMap as 4 digits.

For example, yun field '23' -> test field '0023' / yun field '123' -> test field '0123'

What can I do?

Comment: What is the test field type? If it's numeric (integer or float) you can't, you can calculate a string field str(!yun!).zfill(4) in python field calculator which will pad with up to 4 0s'.

Comment: maybe yun field is integer, test field is text, I'm sorry, but can you tell me in detail? I do this for the first time. it be stressed

Answer (score 3):

Open the attribute table in ArcMap by right clicking on the layer in the table of contents and select *open attribute table*. When the table appears right click on the top of the column *test_field* and select field calculator.

Be sure to set the python parser:

[image]

Then enter the calc:

```
str(!yun!).zfill(4)
```

yun is the source field name so it gets exclamation marks (!) around it. This function turns the value of yun into a string then pads with 4 0s' ([zfill](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_zfill.htm)).

Comment: @김성헌 If it solves your problem then press the green check mark(in answer) and thus accept it as an anser and likewise press the up-arrow to give the anwser credit.